# Adding a condition for success or error using jQuery ajax + Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

When using the Wordpress "nonce" system to authenticate an AJAX request, a response of "-1" is returned if the authentication fails.  Rather than doing something like this in every jQuery.ajax success function:

```
success: function(msg){
    if (msg == '-1')
        console.debug('error')
    else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

is it possible to somehow augment jQuery and add a condition for my application that error: rather than success: is fired when the message returned is "-1"?  Obviously much cleaner than a bunch of the same if statements.

I realize the normal response is to have the controller return a 4xx header, but would rather not have the Wordpress plugin change the default behaviour of the ajax handler and possibly mess up other Wordpress plugins.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here... you want jQuery Ajax to catch the error state... which can only be done if the response code is other than 200... but you dont want to change the code away from 200?

Answer (score 1):

There is also an error callback

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Example

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://somewhere.com/index.html'
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    //do stuff
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //do stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: But if the response is just '-1' with a 200 OK status, success: is fired rather than error: (this is how the jQuery.ajax function was designed, but wondering if there's a clean way to add additional conditions for what an 'error' is rather than the same if condition in every success: handler...)

Comment: There is no way.  Thats what I was trying to nicely say in my last comment... what you are trying to do is BAD.  The call is a success, the return code is a -1.  You would have to modify jQuery to break it so you can make your scenario work.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to modify core jQuery code, I'm just trying to avoid a bunch of repeated if statements checking for -1 across all the individual jQuery.ajax() calls.  I also did not want to modify the default behaviour of Wordpress failing its authentication check by returning a non-200 status.  Thanks for confirming that it cannot be done without modifying the core jQuery code!